# Spark throws FileNotFoundException and says 'Refresh Table tablename'

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ignite

I am reading a file from Ignite File System using spark. 
File system URI igfs://myfs@hostname:4500/path/to/file.
Spark jobs able to read a file by few jobs, but some of the jobs says FileNotFoundException.
Finally execution ends up with FileNotFoundException.
I tested the same code with small files and I was working fine.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that path immutable? Usually such error happens when separate process overwrite the same path in parallel.

Comment: Also check for the job owners and permissions on that file.

Comment: Thanks for your answers :) , I noticed that 2 ignite processes were running in the same machine... so I killed both and started only one,then it's started working.